# Different Print preview in Chrome and Mozila Firefox

Tags: css, printing, print-preview

http://exrx.net/concrete5/extras/food-exchange-journal

This is the page link and page contains some tables. When I try to print this page in Firefox browser, Print Preview is showing full table and works fine.
But when I print same page in Google Chrome Browser, it shows half table and preview is not same as Firefox.
What could be the reason ? Is google chrome ignoring print Media Query ?
Below is CSS that I have used in print media query.

```
@media print {

    #mobileNav{ display:none !important;}
    .container { width: auto; }
    td {    font-size:0.6em; }
    #mobileAssets {display:none !important;}
}
```

Comment: Try with `width:100%;` on `.container`, and maybe on `body` and `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because transition kits css which causing print media queries.
Example:
transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;